# XSLT: Call template with parameter from template which provides the paramenter

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to call template2 from inside template1, and provide it with a parameter from template1.

Right now, I have something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="template1" match="home/sentences/sentence">
        <xsl:if test="something...">
            <new_sentence>  
                <!-- ...other unrelated stuff... -->

                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('get_sentence_attribute', tokenRef/@tokID)"/>

                <!--Here I point to the template I made for tokens. 
                But I also wish to provide it with the value returned by get_sentence_attribute -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="../../tokens"/>
            </new_sentence>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="template2" match="home/tokens">
      <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

Basically I need to make sure that the values selected by my tokens template, match the sentence_attribute I get in my sentence template. I've googled around and found the `<xsl:with-param>` element; but it's pretty confusing to me and I'm not even sure if it's what I need.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- 1. store your results in a variable -->
<xsl:variable name="result">
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('get_sentence_attribute', tokenRef/@tokID)"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- 2. call your template with a param value -->
<xsl:call-template name="named-template">
    <xsl:with-param name="param1" value="$result"/>
</xsl:call-template/>

...
...

<!-- 3. you need to declare your template to accept a parameter -->
<xsl:template name="named-template">
    <xsl:param name="param1"/>

    <!-- do stuff with $param1-->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I want a "local" variable, created inside `template1`, and passed to template2. So should I add `1.` and `2.` inside `template1` and `3.` inside `template2`? I'm getting a "parsing xslt stylesheet failed"

Comment: I had a few problems, but trial and error fixed everything... You do have a syntax error though: `</xsl:call-template/>`. I've accepted your answer, but fix the `/>`. Also, in the future, when you post an answer, try to respond with an example based on the question's sample code; it makes things much easier.